# How can I define a ScalaCheck generator that produces a subset of a sequence's elements?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

How can I pick a subset of the elements of a sequence?

For instance, if I had the sequence `Seq(1,2,3,4,5)`, I'd like each call to my generator to produce something like

```
Seq(1,4)
```

or

```
Seq(1,2,3,5)
```

or

```
Seq()
```

How can I define such a generator?

Comment: Does the `Seq` you pick from have unique elements?

Comment: Yes that is what I had in mind

Comment: Yes, it is not a strict (proper) subset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`org.scalacheck.Gen.someOf`](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/73c8a9f0dcae1d993b3e5afc467f2ab8e241181d/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Gen.scala#L512) is a generator that picks a random number of elements from an iterable:

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalacheck.Gen

scala> val baseSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
baseSeq: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val myGen = Gen.someOf(baseSeq).map(_.toSeq)
myGen: org.scalacheck.Gen[Seq[Int]] = org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$6@ff6a218

scala> myGen.sample.head
res0: Seq[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)

scala> myGen.sample.head
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> myGen.sample.head
res2: Seq[Int] = List()
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the probability for each element to show up in your result.  For example, for any element to show up with 50% chance, you can use the following.  Hope this helps.

```
import scala.util.Random
val s = Seq(1,2,3,4,5)
s filter { i => Random.nextInt(2) == 1 }
```

Comment: This is in the context of ScalaCheck so OP is looking for return type like `Gen[Seq[Int]]`.